# Adding script within jsx

Tags: reactjs, jsx

In my jsx file I have the following function:

```
function GetComments({commentsArray}) {
        return commentsArray.map((comment) => {
        let localId = comment.LocalId;
          return (
            <div className="comments-container">
                <div className="commenter">
                    <span className="id-label">{comment.LocalId}</span>
                        <script>
                            if (comment.ParentCommentId !== null) {
                               document.write("<span class=reply title=in reply to " + comment.LocalId + "></span>") 
                            }
                        </script>
                </div>
            </div>
          );
        });
}
```

Now I don't get any errors but when that script tag part is in there, the page just doesn't load, it's just constantly stuck trying to load. Where have I gone wrong with adding a script to this? I am only wanting that element created when that condition is met. I have been looking online and I see that it's different  in jsx for adding scripts but confused on how to correctly implement my script

Comment: Is it necessary for it to be contained within a <script> tag? Conditional rendering would work, as dheeraj pointed out, but I think the script and document.write() can be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code, the biggest of which is the use of `document.write`, which you should never be using in react code. To understand why, it's important to realize that one of the most fundamental design goals of react is to abstract any direct manipulation of the DOM away from the programmer and instead allow them to specify the way in which a lighter weight virtual DOM *reacts* to state changes. Try something like the following:

```
export function GetComments({ commentsArray }) {
  return (
    <>
      {commentsArray.map((comment) => {
        const localId = comment.LocalId;
        return (
          <div key={localId} className="comments-container">
            <div className="commenter">
              <span className="id-label">{localId}</span>
              {comment.ParentCommentId && (
                <span className="reply" title={`in reply to ${localId}`} />
              )}
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
}
```

In addition to doing away with `document.write`, this addresses the following issues:

1. Consistent use of `localId`.
2. [Conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) to render the `"reply"` `span` when `comment.ParentCommentId` is truthy.
3. [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to more clearly express the "in reply to" string. This is maybe a bit more of a style issue than a functional one, but template literals are the modern way to format variables into string templates.
4. The use of [key](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) inside the map to "help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed."
5. Wrapping the whole `map` expression in a [fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) so that it has a return type which is not an array, which is a requirement for it being used as a JSX element.

Comment: Thank for the really detailed answer, much appreciated. However would you know why for the <> just after the first return I am getting an "unexpected token" error?

Comment: You could be using an older version of react. The so-called short syntax for fragments was introduced in [v16.2.0](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/11/28/react-v16.2.0-fragment-support.html). If you are for some reason tied to an earlier version, you can use `<React.Fragment> ... </React.Fragment>` instead.

Comment: ah that was it thanks. Still having an issue though as it is printing out comment.ParentCommentId && for each element rather than that being a condition if that makes sense?

Comment: That was my fault forgetting to surround that section in curly braces. Please see the revised code.

Comment: That was it, working now. Thank you for that and thanks again for the in depth explanation, given me a much better understanding on how it works and how I should be going about this

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to actually come up with a way to solve the issue, don't know if this is the best way.

I created an additional function where I pass the id into it and do the check there.

```
function ParentIdCheck({id}) {
    if (id !== null) {
        return(
            <span className="reply" title={"in reply to " + id}></span>
        );
    }
}
```

and now the original function looks like:

```
function GetComments({commentsArray}) {
        return commentsArray.map((comment) => {
        let localId = comment.LocalId;
          return (
            <div className="comments-container">
                <div className="commenter">
                    <span className="id-label">{comment.LocalId}</span>
                    <ParentIdCheck id = {comment.ParentCommentId}/>
                </div>
            </div>
          );
        });
}
```

I don't know if this is the best way though, so open to suggestions on how to improve this